# Cannot override .MuiInputLabel-root

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Codepen of my current attempt: https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-stallman-f0vmkb?file=/src/App.js

I'm not really sure what is wrong here but I'm sure I'm overlooking something.

I got the class name to override from the MUI docs https://mui.com/material-ui/api/input-label/#css

As an aside, is this how I should be handling styles in MUI 5? Is there a preferred alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the space between '&' and className in styled function

Refer: https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-mahavira-mxxssl